# Salesforce validation for Email

Tags: validation, salesforce, visualforce, apex

I have a custom field called Email_address and I want to set-up a validation that sends an error message if the email isn't a gmail address. How would I set this up?

Also, is there a way to send an error message if the email address isn't unique?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you mean by 'send an error.'

If you want to prevent incorrect entry, use a validation rule.  I'd generally use a [regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16200965/regular-expression-validate-gmail-addresses) to evaluate something like an email address, but if you're uncomfortable with them you can also use something like `RIGHT(my_field__c, 9) <> "gmail.com"`.  If, for some reason, you want to be notified of incorrect email addresses but still allow them to be entered, you can use a workflow that behaves mostly the same way.

Preventing duplicate email addresses is a bit more difficult unless you want to venture into trigger-land, which is massive overkill for something like this IMHO.  You can make the field a unique ID in the custom field creation wizard (although I believe you only get a finite number of these), but other than that I don't know of a way that doesn't involve a trigger and a SOQL query.

Comment: gmail.com and googlemail.com should be considered ;) I hink by default you get 3 unique fields / object but you can contact support for more. And it's worth noting the VLOOKUP function - but it's more about "does this value exist in 'dictionary'" & works only by name field on the 'dictionary' object.